# Network shares that a Computer has connected to

Tags: forensics

I know that Windows 7 (Registry) stores the shares that a machine has connected to. Can anybody tell me what the registry location is ?

According to : [Forensic Focus](http://www.forensicfocus.com/a-forensic-analysis-of-the-windows-registry), it should be under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

but its not here. Help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try looking under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network` that will show you the current mapped network drives for the current user based on the drive letter. Or `HKEY_Users\<sid>\Network` for a particular user (based on the SID).

While my answer will show what drives a user has mapped to a drive letter, adric's will show you the drives accessed that were not mapped to a drive letter (via UNC, etc).

Same path concept applies:

Current User:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPounts2
```

Specific User (by SID):

```
HKU\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPounts2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some stuff under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2 that looks promising.

Sorry, my Win7 machine hasn't been on very many network shares in it's lifetime but I think they are all there, thought some are just GUIDs.